# How do you count train stations?

Tags: counters

What would be the counter for train stations?

For example, "two more stops" would be 後駅を**二つ**...?
It seems a bit unnatural.

Answer (score 5):

you can say things like:

- ２個{こ}先{さき}
- ２つ先
- となりのとなり
- あと二駅{ふたえき｝
- つぎのつぎ

Comment: I think "あと二駅｛ふたえき｝" is commonly used. I use "２つ先｛さき｝" more than "２個先｛こさき｝, though "２個先｛こさき｝" is mainly used by youngsters.

Comment: @mackygoo Good point. I added it as an option. For numbers below 10 個 and つ are generally interchangeable

Comment: 「つぎのつぎ」とかどおでしょ？（counter使わないけど）

Comment: 「二駅」のように何駅まであがれる？「みそ駅」はないでしょうw